# How can I calculate the intercept direction of a constant accelerating missile?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, projectile, rocket-science

I'm simulating missiles in 3d space and want the missiles to intercept a target which has constant velocity.

Given the targets velocity is "u" a vector and the missiles acceleration rate is "a" a constant scalar
what is the formula to calculate the direction the missile should be facing to intercept the target.

I have tried using the quadratic formula but that only works on constant speed missiles, I tried to run it iteratively: calculate the intercept position find the average velocity the missiles will have to reach that point and give that as the new speed input but it didn't work, its possible I messed up the formula somewhere or maybe that's just not a proper way to calculate it.

I'm lost any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Radiodrome: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiodrome This should give you some idea of the math involved.

Comment: @Gert The example you cite assumes constant velocity. It is a bit more complicated with constant acceleration of the missile.

Comment: @akifdur Can we assume that the missile is always directed towards the target and that the **acceleration magnitude** is constant? You do not specify these assumptions in your question..

Comment: @MarkoGulin Of course but the Wiki entry shows the math principle. Easy adjusted for constant acceleration...

Comment: A pursuit curve is the case where the missile accelerates directly towards the apparent position of the target. If you want a pursuit curve solution, look here.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3114649/pursuit-curve-modification   Also, do some searches on pursuit curve if that is not what you need.

Comment: Related post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/696304/2451

Answer (score 1):

From your question

> Given the targets velocity is "u" and the missiles acceleration rate is "a" what is the formula to calculate the direction the missile should be facing to intercept the target.

I infer that you are analyzing a simple problem of straight-line motion for both target and missile. This problem would be (much) more complicated to analyze if the missile would follow a trajectory in which it is always directed towards the target. That would be a form of a well-known *radiodrome* (pursuit curve) problem.

---

Since the target moves in a straight line, we can orient our coordinate system such that the target is moving along one of the axis. Let $\vec{r}_m(t)$ and $\vec{r}_t(t)$ be missile and target position at time $t$, where

$$\vec{r}_m(0) = \vec{0} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \vec{r}_t(t) = \vec{r}_t(0) + (v_t t) \hat{k} = x_0 \hat{\imath} + y_0 \hat{\jmath} + (z_0 + v_t t) \hat{k}$$

The problem is to find an angle for $\vec{r}_m$ vector such that the missile and the target meet at time $t_0$.

The distance of the missile and the target from the origin at time $t$ is

$$|\vec{r}_m(t)| = \frac{1}{2} a t^2 \quad \text{and} \quad |\vec{r}_t(t)| = \sqrt{x_0^2 + y_0^2 + (z_0 + v_t t)^2} = \sqrt{d_0^2 + (2 z_0 + v_t t) (v_t t)}$$

where it is assumed that the missile starts from rest, and $d_0^2 = x_0^2 + y_0^2 + z_0^2$ is the initial distance between the missile and the target.

At time $t = t_0$ the missile and the target meet, which means $\vec{r}_m(t_0) = \vec{r}_t(t_0)$ and

$$|\vec{r}_m(t_0)| = |\vec{r}_t(t_0)| \quad \rightarrow \quad \frac{a^2}{4} t_0^4 - v_t^2 t_0^2 - 2 z_0 v_t t_0 - d_0^2 = 0$$

Solve the above quartic equation to get $t_0$ and then find the three (or two) angles of the $\vec{r}_t(t_0)$ vector. The missile needs to be launched at exactly these angles.